# How to free these ports on Ubuntu-18.04

Tags: server, 18.04, redis

I am installing Redis Enterprise on Ubuntu 18.04 and it requires these ports to be opened for Redis cluster. I have created a new VM but not sure why these ports are opened and how can I make these available for Redis.

Ports: 17659, 28130 ,28230,13000,12563

```
admx@Ubuntu18-1:~/Redis$ sudo lsof -i:17659
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
MetricsEx 2151 root   13u  IPv4  28975      0t0  UDP localhost:17659
admx@Ubuntu18-1:~/Redis$ sudo lsof -i:28130
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mdsd    1399 syslog   37u  IPv4  25719      0t0  TCP localhost:28130 (LISTEN)
admx@Ubuntu18-1:~/Redis$ sudo lsof -i:28230
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mdsd    1399 syslog   39u  IPv4  25720      0t0  TCP localhost:28230 (LISTEN)
admx@Ubuntu18-1:~/Redis$ sudo lsof -i:13000
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
amacoreag 1096 root   11u  IPv4  24848      0t0  TCP localhost:13000 (LISTEN)
admx@Ubuntu18-1:~/Redis$ sudo lsof -i:12563
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
amacoreag 1096 root   12u  IPv4  24859      0t0  TCP localhost:12563 (LISTEN)
admx@Ubuntu18-1:~/Redis$ sudo lsof -i:53



    admx@Ubuntu18-1:~$ sudo ss -tulpn
NetidState  Recv-Q Send-Q                    Local Address:Port    Peer Address:                                                                                                             Port                                                                                                                                                                                         
udp  UNCONN 0      0                         10.1.0.4%eth0:68           0.0.0.0:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("systemd-network",pid=931,fd=19))
udp  UNCONN 0      0                              10.1.0.4:123          0.0.0.0:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("ntpd",pid=5284,fd=19))
udp  UNCONN 0      0                             127.0.0.1:123          0.0.0.0:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("ntpd",pid=5284,fd=18))
udp  UNCONN 0      0                               0.0.0.0:123          0.0.0.0:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("ntpd",pid=5284,fd=17))
udp  UNCONN 0      0                             127.0.0.1:17659        0.0.0.0:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("MetricsExtensio",pid=2151,fd=13))
udp  UNCONN 0      0       [fe80::20d:3aff:fe55:bef2]%eth0:123             [::]:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("ntpd",pid=5284,fd=21))
udp  UNCONN 0      0                                 [::1]:123             [::]:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("ntpd",pid=5284,fd=20))
udp  UNCONN 0      0                                  [::]:123             [::]:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("ntpd",pid=5284,fd=16))
tcp  LISTEN 0      4096                          127.0.0.1:8002         0.0.0.0:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("envoy",pid=6361,fd=21))
tcp  LISTEN 0      10                            127.0.0.1:28130        0.0.0.0:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("mdsd",pid=1399,fd=37))
tcp  LISTEN 0      4096                          127.0.0.1:8004         0.0.0.0:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("envoy_control_p",pid=6347,fd=15))
tcp  LISTEN 0      4096                          127.0.0.1:8006         0.0.0.0:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("envoy",pid=6348,fd=21))
tcp  LISTEN 0      10                            127.0.0.1:28230        0.0.0.0:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("mdsd",pid=1399,fd=39))
tcp  LISTEN 0      4096                          127.0.0.1:13000        0.0.0.0:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("amacoreagent",pid=1096,fd=11))
tcp  LISTEN 0      4096                          127.0.0.1:3343         0.0.0.0:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("envoy_control_p",pid=6347,fd=14))
tcp  LISTEN 0      4096                            0.0.0.0:3344         0.0.0.0:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("envoy",pid=6348,fd=23))
tcp  LISTEN 0      4096                            0.0.0.0:3344         0.0.0.0:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("envoy",pid=6348,fd=22))
tcp  LISTEN 0      4096                          127.0.0.1:12563        0.0.0.0:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("amacoreagent",pid=1096,fd=12))
tcp  LISTEN 0      128                             0.0.0.0:22           0.0.0.0:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("sshd",pid=1265,fd=3))
tcp  LISTEN 0      1024                          127.0.0.1:9080         0.0.0.0:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("gunicorn: worke",pid=7125,fd=10),("gunicorn: worke",pid=7120,fd=10),("                                                                                                             gunicorn: worke",pid=7114,fd=10),("gunicorn: worke",pid=7107,fd=10),("gunicorn:                                                                                                              worke",pid=7102,fd=10),("gunicorn: worke",pid=7097,fd=10),("gunicorn: maste",pid                                                                                                             =6364,fd=10))
tcp  LISTEN 0      1024                          127.0.0.1:9081         0.0.0.0:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("gunicorn: worke",pid=7081,fd=11),("gunicorn: worke",pid=7079,fd=11),("                                                                                                             gunicorn: worke",pid=7076,fd=11),("gunicorn: worke",pid=7075,fd=11),("gunicorn:                                                                                                              maste",pid=6370,fd=11))
tcp  LISTEN 0      128                           127.0.0.1:8444         0.0.0.0:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("cm_server",pid=6385,fd=7))
tcp  LISTEN 0      4096                                  *:9443               *:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("envoy",pid=6361,fd=32))
tcp  LISTEN 0      4096                                  *:9443               *:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("envoy",pid=6361,fd=33))
tcp  LISTEN 0      4096                                  *:8070               *:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("envoy",pid=6361,fd=36))
tcp  LISTEN 0      4096                                  *:8070               *:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("envoy",pid=6361,fd=37))
tcp  LISTEN 0      4096                                  *:8080               *:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("envoy",pid=6361,fd=38))
tcp  LISTEN 0      4096                                  *:8080               *:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("envoy",pid=6361,fd=39))
tcp  LISTEN 0      128                                [::]:22              [::]:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("sshd",pid=1265,fd=4))
tcp  LISTEN 0      2                                 [::1]:3350            [::]:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("xrdp-sesman",pid=1178,fd=7))
tcp  LISTEN 0      4096                                  *:8443               *:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("envoy",pid=6361,fd=34))
tcp  LISTEN 0      4096                                  *:8443               *:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("envoy",pid=6361,fd=35))
tcp  LISTEN 0      2                                     *:3389               *:                                                                                                             *                                                                                                                                                                                             users:(("xrdp",pid=1263,fd=11))
```

Comment: @guiverc there is no tag available for 18.04. So had to select these.

Comment: output is returned during redis installation. @user535733

Comment: @user535733 im able to free port 53. Updating question with more details.

Comment: @user535733 updated

Comment: The listed ports are in use by other applications, and now you have TWO agreeing lists of those applications. For example, port 13000 is being used by an application called `amacoreagent`. Google suggests that application some kind of Azure monitoring agent. If you are using Azure, then consult their support for what it is and how to get it to play nicely with Redis (possible hint: Azure sells a compatible Redis product). If you are not using Azure, then why do you have it installed? Rinse and repeat for your other ports.

Comment: actually this is azure VM and I want to install redis enterprise manually. I am not using Azure Cache Redis product. @user535733